# Visual Studio: Debugging Chrome with Source?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging, google-chrome, debug-symbols

I've managed to set up the download symbols for Google Chrome (Dev channel) in Visual Studio. This is helpful for understanding the *disassembly*, but when I step into a function, I want to see the **C++** source code. (It opens up a dialog, letting me find the source file, which I of course don't have.)

Is there a server from which I can have Visual Studio automatically find the matching version of the C++ source file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [this](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/debugging) article, you can configure VS or windbg to download symbols from http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols and https://chromium-browser-symsrv.commondatastorage.googleapis.com

Other workaround of that is to compile the entire source on your side... (but you already know that :))

Comment: Yeah but when I do that, it only downloads the `PDB` files -- it still asks for the C++ source files to show me source code. (And no, I don't want to recompile the entire thing, lol.)

Comment: Can you check if its loading the modules properly? `Debug > WIndows > Modules`. One other thing you can try is that if its asking for the source cpp file, browse and point to it manually in the source code folder (assuming you've got downloaded the source code to some folder on your side).

Comment: I'll try and see the thing about the modules. However, `assuming you've got downloaded the source code to some folder on your side` --> the whole point is to avoid that, because I don't know how to find the *correct version* of the source code for my build. Can't VS automatically find the source file and download it as needed somehow?

Comment: Well, if your debug symbols can be loaded correctly, you don't the original source as they contain all the source info. Otherwise, VS has no clue to locate them. Curious though, doesn't chrome build come bundled with the source code?

Comment: The symbols *are* loaded correctly: it took a while to download the multi-hundred-megabyte PDB files (I have them in front of me), and I can see the identifier names in the disassembly. However, when I run it, it pops up a window asking to open `some_file.cc`, which I of course don't have.
Not sure what you mean by coming "bundled" with the source code... the source code is pretty darn big, much larger than the ~120-MB browser. And I have no idea **which version** of the source code I need, that's the real problem -- that's why I need automatic download of the right version.

Comment: Interesting. Now I'm curious to try it myself. Can you tell me what are you trying to debug?

Comment: I'm trying to see when/how the `--single-process` flag is interpreted, what it does, etc.

Comment: Hey, found couple of things: If you downloaded thru their dev channel (either dev or canary build), you probbaly have a release build. That explains why you don't see source code even with symbol files. Now if you know the release number, you can get its corresponding src from `http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/branches/[xxx]` where xxx is the revision number [14.0.829.1 -> branches/829]. Once you have that, you can search-n-browse to the cpp file when prompted and VS will remember that.

Comment: Oh yes, it's definitely a release build -- a debug build wouldn't be very usable because of how slow it would be! :) I'm not sure how that explains anything about the source files/symbol files, though -- release and debug are about compiler optimizations, but how is that actually related to the source? (Thanks for the link, though, that's helpful!)

Comment: You said it yourself! Since the code can possibly be optimized, it cannot be linked to the original source. Now the `pdb` file for a release build is significantly smaller than the `pdb` file for a debug build. Debug build `pdb` will contain detailed source code, line number info etc as it is created using `/debug:full` flag as opposed to `/debug:pdbonly` for release build. More here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241903.aspx

Comment: Ohh I see, I totally forgot that there's more than 1 kind of PDB. Interesting, thanks for the info. +1

Answer (score 5):

Using a symbol server (as described in http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/debugging) is enough to get you the PDBs, but will not by itself get you source. To get the source code requires enabling source indexing.

Source indexing during builds works by adding extra data to the PDB file (so getting the PDB files was the correct first step) that tells the debuggers how to retrieve source files from version control. However this feature is off by default in both windbg and Visual Studio. That is, by default windbg and Visual Studio ignore the source indexing information which Chrome adds.

In Visual Studio (all versions since about 2002) you can enable it by going to Tools-> Options-> Debugging-> General-> Enable source server support. You may also want to check "Print source server diagnostic messages to the Output window" in case it doesn't work initially.

In windbg you can type ".srcfix" into the command window, or go to File-> Source File Path and type SRV* into the source path dialog. If you want diagnostics then type "!sym noisy" into the command window.

Note that as of December 2014 it is recommended that you use https rather than http for retrieving Chrome symbols, to improve security, so use https://chromium-browser-symsrv.commondatastorage.googleapis.com as the symbol server address.

For more details on source indexing see this blog post which I wrote:

https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2011/11/11/source-indexing-is-underused-awesomeness/