# Chromium debugging on Windows environment

Tags: c++, visual-studio, google-chrome, debugging, chromium

How can I debug chrome itself on Windows platform, I am familiar with Visual Studio and c# debugging.

[This is the code part what I am interested in](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/components/autofill/content/renderer/password_form_conversion_utils.cc#165).

Should I build from source? or it is possible to log all of the necessary data without messing with the source code?

I looked around online but I am not familiar with robust C++ projects. (like symbol tables etc, …)

**So my question is:**

What is the easiest way to debug step by step that method what is it in the link?

Comment: Do you want to debug Chrome or Chromium? If it's the latter one then download it's source code and use this command line to start debugging it: devenv /debugexe chrome.exe

Comment: You should look at this page: https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos

Comment: @Peter, Is it the way you want to debug the chrome? Any update for this issue now?

Comment: yes I figure out, i gonna make a detailed description how to do it, the guys here give me a good direction to start but it was more complicated

Comment: @Peter, If this issue has been resolved, you could share your solution here, and then mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issue as yours. Have a nice day:)

Comment: done, please feel free to comment or suggest how I can improve my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

step by step instructions for debugging chrome via vs 2017 
in my example I am going to use "c:\Files\Work\chromium\" folder

### Installs:

install VS2017 with "Desktop development with c++"  from: https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/ 
[image]

step install python 2.x with PATH from: https://www.python.org/downloads/ 
[image]

get depot_tools from: https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-infra/depot_tools.zip

unzip it into "c:\Files\Work\chromium\" Use right click "Extract All..."  because of the hidden files

### open powerhsell

Change folder:

> cd c:\Files\Work\chromium\

check python installed correctly:

> python --version
>
> Python 2.7.13

setup environment variable:

> $env:DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN=0
>
> $env:GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2017
>
> $env:path = $env:path + ";c:\Files\Work\chromium\depot_tools\"

Create folder for chromium srouce code:

> mkdir chromium && cd chromium

Download the source code (20gb it takes for a while)

> fetch chromium
>
> gclient sync

Switch to src folder:

> cd src

generate vs2017 project file:

> gn gen --ide=vs2017 --filter//chrome/* --args="is_component_build = true is_debug = true remove_webcore_debug_symbols = true" out\Default

### Open Visual Studio 2017:

Enable source server:

Tools-> Options-> Debugging-> General-> "Enable source server support" 
with "Print Source server diagnostic messages..." 
[image]

Add Symbols:

Tools-> Options-> Debugging-> Symbols 
add 
https://chromium-browser-symsrv.commondatastorage.googleapis.com 
and 
http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols 
with cache 
[image]

restart VS2017

open chromium project (it takes for a while) 
c:\Files\Work\chromium\chromium\src\out\Default\all.sln project

### Start Debugging:

Debug -> Attach to Process 
Set it to Attach to Native code:

[image]

When you need to debug chrome attach to main chrome process when you need to debug renderer attach to tab use Chrome Task Manager to figure out Process ID to open Task manager use: `shift+esc`

To Set Up break points:

Put breakpoint, right click -> conditions 
and Check "Allow the source code to be different from the original"

[image]

If VS asking to checkout for the source press ok.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the whole source code, it would be easy for you to debug your app.

Like this issue here:

[Visual Studio: Debugging Chrome with Source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802292/visual-studio-debugging-chrome-with-source)

If you really want to debug the Chrome browser, you could really run it in your VS. Of you could get the symbols files for it, and then get some debugging information from the PDB file directly.